# Use wildcard in bash with a path containing spaces

Tags: bash

I have the below command which I want to run through a bash for loop:

```
inputdir="/mnt/c/Users/OneDrive - ABC/DNA/raw_vcf"
vcfs="(${inputdir}/*.vcf.gz)"
for v in "${vcfs[@]}"
do
     echo "input: $v"
done
```

I got

```
input: /mnt/c/Users/OneDrive - ABC/DNA/raw_vcf/*.vcf.gz
```

I think it might be due to the spaces in the path. How to fix this problem?

Comment: `*` isn't expanded inside quotes (you can try `echo *` vs `echo "*"`)

Comment: Thanks but there're spaces in the path, how to use it without quotes. Can you put it in an answer?

Comment: I actually would have expected the code in the question to yield `input: (/mnt/c/Users/OneDrive - ABC/DNA/raw_vcf/*.vcf.gz)` _with the parens_, since quoting makes them literal data rather than syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote only the expansion containing the space, and not the glob (and certainly not the parenthesis).

```
vcfs=( "$inputdir"/*.vcf.gz )
```